# How to exit a non void method in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a method that returns an `ItemCollection`, I want to stop the function early if there is no information provided. I would normally do this with a return; however as my method expects an `ItemCollection` it fails. I have this as a work around but it seems frankly hacky. Is there something I am missing. I tried just return; and I would prefer not throw an exception.

```
    private ItemCollection loadLeft_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var leftUser = UsrLeft.Text;
        if (leftUser == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No User Entered");
            GroupListLeft.Items.Add("");
            var fail = GroupListLeft.Items;

            return fail;
        }

        //Succesful test do stuff 
        var leftItems = GroupListLeft.Items;

        return leftItems;
     }
```

Comment: Andrew, you are probably getting started with programming, read about the programming language you use (C# in this case) and OOD, also remember that you decide what you code has to behave.
This means that if you want to validate if the user is empty, because it should not, you can decide to throw an exception such ArgumentException. Then as suggested you can return null, but then handle it, in the code consuming this method, or an empty ItemCollection.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have few options:

- throw a new `Exception` (maybe even a custom one like `NoUserEnteredException("someText")`).
- return `null`
- return an empty collection or dummy object (see Null-object pattern)

The last one is better choice, in this case you don't need write a null-check or a try-catch section in client code.

Comment: Didn't think of null, but I went with the empty collection idea instead. That works well.

Comment: @Andrew As for me, everytime I need that kind of job, I return null, so it is easy to check when you launch the function, if null you met a problem, else you read the result (you can get an empty collection)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to return something that equates to an `ItemCollection`, depending on how you may want the calling procedures to handle such a return you could use a `null` return:

```
    if (leftUser == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No User Entered");
        return null;
    }
```

Or return a new `ItemCollection` e.g.

```
    if (leftUser == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No User Entered");
        return new ItemCollection();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to return null, like

```
private ItemCollection loadLeft_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    var leftUser = UsrLeft.Text;
    if (leftUser == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No User Entered");

        return null;
    }

    //Succesful test do stuff 
    var leftItems = GroupListLeft.Items;

    return leftItems;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "return null" which I do from time to time, but its not a good coding convention. Another option is to throw an exception and then catch it. Both is bad coding conventions and makes the code that uses this button add some rather obscure logic and dependencies.

From studying SOLID principles I would argue a better solution is to make a new type of object to return. f.ex. one that holds a list, but also a status message and then make it react a bit like when you have an HTTP request that depends on a success and otherwise cannot expect to have any content. This way, the object makes it clearer what to expect.

A fourth option, since this sounds UI related, is to possible have the click callback somehow and either update the collection, or update with an error message directly. But this might also be a bad coding convention that has impractical dependencies in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to return an object when you click on something.
(I am no expert in WPF, i don't know if this is possible).

I would encapsulate the function that returns the `ItemCollection` in a separate function and check whether the User is valid BEFORE calling this function.

This way you ensure that the `ItemCollection` is always valid (because you don't even try to retrieve it with an invalid user). Something like this:

```
    private void loadLeft_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        var leftUser = UsrLeft.Text;
        if(leftUser != "") {
            ItemCollection coll = getItemCollectionForUser(leftUser);
        }else {
            //Error Handling
        }
    }

    private ItemCollection getItemCollectionForUser(string user) {
       //return ItemCollection here
    }
```

Note how I wrote a separate function that returns the `ItemCollection` and the `Click` function returns nothing.